# Create intervals with 'datenum'

Tags: matlab

I am creating the limits for an equally spaced time series and I need to be able to change the  time interval (1min, 5min, 10min, 15min, 30min, 60min etc.). My bounds are opening and closing time of the market. The stocks I am working on trades from 17.00 to 16.15 of the day after.
Here is what I am using:

```
timevec=datenum(2013,1,1,17,0:1*interval:1395,0)';
% It creates a time vector from 1-1-2013 17.00.00 to 1-2-2013 16.15.00 
% spaced by "1min*interval"
```

The formula to be used is pretty simple but a problem arise if I need to use 10min or 30min as the result would be:
(10min)

```
02-Jan-2013 15:50:00
02-Jan-2013 16:00:00
02-Jan-2013 16:10:00
```

(30min)

```
02-Jan-2013 15:30:00
02-Jan-2013 16:00:00
```

What I would like to have is an extra interval 16:20:00 for the ten min case and 16:30:00 for the 30min case. The only solution I can come up with is moving the bound to 16:30 and adding an if statement to remove the extra observations in case they are not needed or keep the bound at 16:15:00 and adding an if statement to add the extra observation in case they are needed.
Is there anyway to do a one-line able to treat these two cases?

Comment: +1 for a well formulated question with examples, working code and description of attempted solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab creates ranges such that all values are inside the limits. If you want to add one additional value right outside the limits, you can modify the upper limit by adding almost one interval length to the end:

```
step = 15;
1:step:100+0.99*step

ans =
     1    16    31    46    61    76    91   106
```

Comment: Apparently when using 60min as interval it outputs 25 hours, repeating the first one as last as well. While is not a problem when using dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS, it may be when only interested in HH:MM:SS (as in my case). I solved the issue with a simple  

`timevec=unique(timevec);`

Any idea to solve this last small problem without adding lines?

Comment: @Gio: why don't you create your range as `datenum(start):datenum(step):datenum(end)` (and add the modification explaned in my post)? This way, you'll have cleaner code. BTW: more lines can sometimes improve readability a lot.